# Isn't the word "if" missing in the sentence below in [basic.link]/10?

Tags: c++, module, language-lawyer

Isn't the word **if** missing, just before the word **all**, in [the sentence below](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#10.sentence-2) at the end of [[basic.link]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#10)?

> As a consequence of these rules, all declarations of an entity are
> attached to the same module; the entity is said to be attached to that
> module.

Comment: I don't believe so, no. The semi-colon is why. It joins the two independent clauses. The rules imply that all declarations of an entity are attached to the same module. Closely related but independent of that, it mentions that the entity itself is said to be attached to that module. We can say that about the entity because the above rules mandate it in a well-formed program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no missing "if", because that's not a valid option. As stated in the rule:

> If two declarations of an entity are attached to different modules, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required if neither is reachable from the other.

The consequence of this is that there's no well-formed program in which multiple declarations could be attached to different modules, and so there's no need for an "if" there.

Also, if there were an "if", then the semi-colon would be incorrect. There would be a comma there instead, or maybe a colon.

Comment: Where exactly is the rule you quoted in the standard?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet It's the first sentence of the rule you quoted in the question. You only pasted the second sentence.